# Should I quit my job where I feel misused?

Tags: quitting, first-job

I'm a developer in a big company (with plenty of employee benefits I won't get anywhere else, performance bonus, 13th month, fitness room, limited homeworking,...).

It's my first job in IT, in a company where IT is an addon.

Lately I'm starting to feel bad as my superiors are not considering my job.

I don't see much opportunity to a "Junior" developer in today's market, but I'm thinking about quitting.

Are my feelings/ideals relevant on the decision of quitting this job ?

Comment: The IT career field is generally a good one ( at least in the US ).  I would not quit your job until you have another offer letter in had.  Its ALWAYS easier to find a job if you currently have one.  You don't want to have to explain the gap in employment if you just quit.

Comment: We can't tell you whether you should quit or not - that's a question better suited for friends and family who know you well.

Comment: Have you talked to your line manager about specific things that are demotivating you?

Comment: IT is a support role in many organizations.  I'm sure Ford Motor Company values IT, but they don't sell servers or SaaS.  They sell cars.  There is a huge role for IT in non-IT companies, but you have to understand you are the stagehand, not the star.  If you can work in that world, you'll likely have a very successful career.

Comment: @Myles  I have been raising alarms since 1 year now about things that are not natural, and which won't work forever the way it is (Also that I need a backup to soak the work charge)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere  Helping people, making their jobs easier, without having to do it myself (That's the latest problem I had, when they told me to do someone else job)

Comment: Another user just tried to make significant edits to your question, and it was rejected for being too drastic. If this was you, please make sure you are logged into your @Drizzt account when making [edit]s.

Comment: @DavidK I reduced, and see it reduced to a 6 line post by removing all "too subjectives" aspects.

Comment: Hmm. They told you to do someone else's job? If A is busy, and X needs help from A who is busy, then B may be told to help X, and B better do it. If you think about leaving, saying "It's not my job, I'm not doing it" may lead to others making the decision for you.

Comment: @Drizzt Ah, I didn't notice that you had reduced the post previously. Your edit was not the problem - another user was adding back in the info you had removed.

Comment: @gnasher729 A is a technician, and we're moving to another building, so yes I guess he is busy, still I'm a developer and I'm also under a lot of pressure, so why should I soak A's work, he will never soak mine

Comment: Does this question still "off-topic" with this formulation ?
As I'm newly employed, I would like to know if how I feel matters in this situation, opposed to if it's everywhere the same, and i should just do my job until I cannot hold it anymore

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There's nothing really good on today's market for a developer with
>   less than 2 years experiences, but I'm questionning myself, should I
>   quit the company ? Or is it the IT which does not fit my "naive"
>   expectations of the job , then quit IT ?

I completely disagree with the first part of this question. There are plenty of good jobs on the market for developers with less than 2 years of experience. I suppose it depends on what you view as "today's market" and what you deem as "good".

Before you quit the company, sit down and do some introspection.

Think about what you want out of your life, your career, and a job. Think about what is important to you, and what is not. You might even make a list and prioritize that.

Then, compare that to what you are experiencing in your current job and how it stacks up against the potential at your current company.

Once you know yourself better, and if you decide your current career path is lacking - then and only then do something about it.

If you should decide to change jobs/companies/professions, then interview hard to find the job that meets your needs. Once you have a new job offer and acceptance, then give your notice, serve it out, and leave professionally.

Whatever you do, don't just quit.

Comment: I think @MistePositive is also right, just quiting isn't the solution. This company also lack the possibility to evolve (from my position, to any manager role), my manager always change subject when I put back on table my first expectation of an "Internal" job.

Answer (score -1):

From comments:

> Have you talked to your line manager about specific things that are demotivating you? – Myles 23 mins ago
>   @Myles I have been raising alarms since 1 year now about things that are not natural, and which won't work forever the way it is (Also that I need a backup to soak the work charge) – Drizzt 13 mins ago

Rather than "raising alarms" I'd suggest a frank and open discussion with management about specific events or aspects of your job that you find demotivating (eg putting x hours into making a change only to have it immediately reverted, doing the job of someone else who isn't IT, etc) and why you find them demotivating (eg it's a waste of time, it's a poor use of your skill set).  Without that conversation it's not reasonable to expect management to fully understand the problem is a retention level issue.

Book a private one on one with your line manager.  Lead with "Some things have been happening here that have impacted my motivation" and go from there.

Comment: I had a few of these meetings, but my n+1 is a concilient manager, he will "talk about this" to my n+2. 
From here my n+2 look at me like a kid, with remarks like "Is it ok for you now ?" during meetings. I just ask to be able to do MY job. That only adds to the overall bad feeling

Comment: @Drizzt Depending on the tone of "Is it ok for you now" I'd suggest this could be a cultural problem.  If you have in fact adequately expressed that you are demotivated by X and you get condescension without any change to X that is a problem with this organization not IT.  That said nobody who wasn't in the room with you is going to be able to judge the tone, how adequately the problems were expressed, or whether X continued rather than some variation of it appeared.  I'd suggest taking a step back and trying again as dispassionately as possible.

Comment: @Drizzt Also if you have access to an employee assistance program that may be a good place to talk out the problem and develop a personalized action plan.

Comment: I will wait to fullfill the main reason for which I was hired, or at least put it on a good track before pulling things like this. As I think it might impact (even if the outcome is good), their trust in me and my future in the company

Comment: @JoeStrazzere While it's true that it's up to each of us to find motivation internally, we all run into externalities that affect us.